# Sum of square of integers – How to visualise it geometrically?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

I watched this YouTube short recently where the author explains the solution geometrically:

https://youtube.com/shorts/PVH5uxHFIGQ?si=hSgj-Q3u-5KVSgf4

The author starts by saying:

"Imagine the square numbers as array of cubes..."

If we know the solution $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ beforehand, by looking at the highest order to be $n^3$, we can start thinking in the direction of using cubes to find the solution geometrically.

What I am interested in, is how can one correctly think of using cubes before knowing the solution? How can a mathematician think along the lines where they can say "Hey, I may be able to use array of cubes to represent each square and find a solution to the problem".

It almost feels that only someone who is a prodigy can think this way, I am here in the hopes that I am terribly wrong because me not being a prodigy, would like to be able to think this way too.

Comment: When you know $\int x^2\,dx=(1/3)x^3+C$, it doesn't take so much imagination to guess $\sum_1^nk^2$ might have something to do with $n^3$. Better: when you know $\Delta n^3=(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$ you expect that reversing the difference to a sum is going to turn a quadrsatic to a cubic.

Comment: FWIK, before arithmetic symbols and calculus were invented – mathematicians used geometrical shapes to solve problems. Wondering if this could be formulated similarly..

Comment: You could certainly imagine an $n-1$ cube wedged into a corner of an $n$-cube, and then decomposing the rest of the $n$-cube into $2$-, $1$-, and $0$-dimensional pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Take the numbers k^2 for k = 1 to n, represent each as square made of legos, k*k units wide and half a unit high. Stack them on top of each other and you get a pyramid n*n wide and n/2 high.

Now take a large cube, n*n*n units in size. You can place one pyramid at the bottom, four each on the sides and one at the top. So 6 pyramids are a total of n^3, and each about n^3/6. Since each has a volume equal to half the sum, the sum is about n^3/3.

Now the pyramids don’t fit exactly, so it’s not precisely n^3/3, but close enough.

The brute force method: The sum is clearly less than n^3 so you guess the sum is an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d, then plug in the values for n=0 to 3, solve for a, b, c, d. Check whether the results are correct for n=4 to 10, check that f(n) - f(n-1) = n^2, and then you can trivially prove it for all n by induction. (The first part is guessing and making sure there are no typos, once you have that the actual proof via induction is trivial).

The brute force method can be used without any thought for sums of any powers.

Answer (score 0):

They might have tried a dozen different ways, and this was the one that finally worked.

They may know the answer already through other means.

They may suspect the answer is some kind of cubic-y thing (if you put the squares on top of one another, you get a pyramid-shape, and pyramids are a sixth of a cube), and just go for it and get lucky.

Regardless, only the pristine finished solution is presented, and you don't get to see all the work that went into polishing it. Only very rarely are elegant proofs something that suddenly materializes in someone's head. Much more often they are the result of real work over long time, maybe lightly guided by intuition and experience. Also note that knowing and collecting elegant proofs appeal to many mathematicians, so just because we *know* many elegant proofs, that doesn't mean we *invent* many of them individually. Only as a collective do we seem to produce these at every turn.

If you want to think these ways, the thing that works best is practice. Write proofs, read other people's proofs of the same results, collect ideas and connections that might help you next time. If you permit a small metaphor, work towards having a large toolbox at your disposal. My personal opinion is that prodigies are prodigies mostly because they love what they do, and spend a lot of time working on it, thinking about it, and obsessing about it.